# как по условию (значение в столбце) искать подстроки в другом столбце на Python циклично

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

Здраствуйте, нужно сделать поиск подстроки в строке по условию во втором столбце. У меня есть 2 dataframe:

```
df1 = {'Descr': ["VALVE, PRESSURE", "pump ttf", "Valve, electrical", "Geeku, electrical","VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY"],
        'N_Product': ["VALVE", "PUMP", "VALVE", "GEEKU","VALVE"],
        }
df2 = {'N_Product': ["VALVE", "VALVE","VALVE", "PUMP", "GEEKU"],
        'M_Product': ["PRESSURE", "BUTTERFLY","", "", "MBA"],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

нужно сравнить значения из колонок N_Product из двух dataframe, если они совпадают, то выполнить поиск соответствующих значений из колонки M_Product(например для Valve - есть 3 соответствия: "PRESSURE", "ELECTRICAL" и ""(пустое значение) в столбце Descr, если оно там есть, то добавить в столбец Result.
Для поиска подстрок в строке использую такой код:

```
c = df2['M_Product'].astype(str).to_list()
def matcher(x):
    for i in c:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan
df1['Res'] = df1['Descr'].apply(matcher)
```

но не знаю как циклически использовать значения только соответствующих M_Product для N_Product.

Желаемый результат:

[image: Желаемый результат]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Прямо как у вас не получилось, но вот вам заготовка, сами доработайте:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='N_Product')
df4 = df3[df3.apply(lambda x: x.M_Product != '' and x.M_Product.lower() in x.Descr.lower(), axis=1)]
df5 = df3[(df3.apply(lambda x: x.M_Product == '' and x.M_Product.lower() in x.Descr.lower(), axis=1)) & ~(df3.index.isin(df4.index))]
df6 = pd.concat([df4,df5])
```

В df6:

|  | Descr | N_Product | M_Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | VALVE, PRESSURE | VALVE | PRESSURE |
| 7 | VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY | VALVE | BUTTERFLY |
| 2 | VALVE, PRESSURE | VALVE |  |
| 5 | Valve, electrical | VALVE |  |
| 8 | VALVE, OVERBOARD, BUTTERFLY | VALVE |  |
| 9 | pump ttf | PUMP |  |

Как у вас сматчилось `MBA` я не понял, у меня не сматчилось.

Ну и ещё нужно подумать, как лишнее убрать. Но приёмы маскирования строк можете эти использовать, просто нужно подумать как правильно скомбинировать условия. Пустые строки сильно всё портят, нужно потом лишнее грамотно убирать, я до конца не довёл.

Comment: пробовал как-то дороботать ваш ответ, но не получилось, данным способом не могу весь скоуп данных использовать что нужно  и не понимаю почему они пропускаються

Comment: возможно ви имеете какие-то идеи?

Comment: Тут думать надо, у меня что-то времени сейчас нет. Надо всё рисовать на бумажке и думать.

Comment: если у вас появиться возможность, буду благодарен за помощь)